# Target dependency: Makefile no rule to make target error

Tags: makefile, dependencies, target

Here is the make file that I am running,

```
.PHONY: build
build: pre_build_script $(OUTPUTDIR)/%.cpp

$(OUTPUTDIR)/%.cpp: $(INTXTDIR)/%.txt
    python.exe $(SOMEDIR)/somepythonscript.py $(INTXTDIR) $(OUTPUTDIR) 

.PHONY: pre_build_script
pre_build_script:
    pythonscript.exe $(PREBUILDDIR)
```

This is the output that I get:

```
$ make build
  pythonscript.exe $(SAMPLEDIR)
  make: *** No rule to make target '../obj/CPP/%.cpp', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

Looks like I'm missing on some sytanx as I get this error inspite of declaring the target dependency. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means `make` cannot find a file named `$(OUTPUTDIR)/%.cpp`, a prerequisite for the first rule.

You cannot use `%` as a wildcard anywhere in a rules like this:

```
 build: pre_build_script $(OUTPUTDIR)/%.cpp
```

it needs to be a part of [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples) or a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage).

You can use `$(wildcard $(OUTPUTDIR)/*.cpp)` to get a complete list of files, but it's an anti-pattern (pun intended). You are supposed to either exactly know what files are used in what rules, or (know it even better and) create a generic pattern rule.

The second pattern rule (one using `somepythonscript.py`) is supposed to work on a single source-target file pair, `$(INTXTDIR)/%.txt` -> `$(OUTPUTDIR)/%.cpp`. The command seems to process all the files in the directory, which is not incremental: it will redo all the work even if only one file was updated.

Comment: Just to note, you cannot use `$(wildcard $(OUTPUTDIR)/%.cpp` because those won't exist when the makefile is parsed... those are the generated files.  You'd need to use `$(patsubst $(INTXTDIR)/%.txt,$(OUTPUTDIR)/%.cpp,$(wildcard $(INTXTDIR)/*.txt))`

Comment: Right, thank you very much. The expression would look simpler if we extract the list of the source files' stems into another variable. But the makefile should rather be rewritten to handle them one-by-one with a pattern rules.

Comment: Thank you @VictorSergienko and @MadScientist . A followup question though, for a target with dependencies like say-> `target: dependency1 dependency2 dependency3 ` does `make target` run all these dependencies in parallel by default or you need to specify it explicitly with -j<n>?

Comment: `make` builds all the `target`'s dependencies before the `target`. By default, it uses one CPU core, unless you specify `-j` - then it can run targets that don't depend on each other (like dependency1 dependency2) in parallel.

Comment: Correct.  Make always runs exactly one command at a time, waiting until it exits to start the next one, unless you specifically ask it to run multiple commands simultaneously with the `-j` option.